# windows 8 remote shutdown: Access is denied(5)

Tags: windows, networking

How to shutdown a remote computer in windows 8? I had tried certain commands like psshutdown, shutdown.exe etc.Everytime i am getting a message called "Access denied(5)". Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The remote computer might have its firewall configured to prevent remote access from other computers. That's why you keep getting the access-denied message.

Comment: No, a firewall would generate a "could not connect" type of message, typically after a timeout, not access denied.

Comment: @HarryJohnston correct.. i hd even enabled remote access on my computer as well as on the remote computer.. Waiting fr a better answer..